# AVPlayer crashes after multiple usage - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, stream, avplayer

I am using an `AVPlayer` object to stream Ultra HD videos in my app. Its usage is pretty straight forward but I'm having an issue after 5~6 streams.

### The issue

The app crashes, the debug session is closed, and I have a message on the console:

> Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

This happens every time after watching 4 or 5 videos on an iPhone 6, and 7 or 8 videos on an iPhone 7.

### What I have tried

Because the debug session ends when my app crashes, I can't see the memory usage exactly when the crash happens. However, before it crashes, the debug session tells me that 2,5% of the RAM is used for the app, even after 4 streams. Not that much!

I recorded my allocations using Instruments and found out that I am never using more than 40MiB which is really not that much.

### My code

I only store one `AVPlayer` in my main User Session, so the debug session and the instruments allocations records include the memory for my player from the beginning.

Each time the user exits the player view controller, I only replace the current player item by nil (Swift), like so:

```
player.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
```

And if the user wants to see another video, again, I replace the current item by the new one.

I tried creating one `AVPlayer` for each video but that didn't change anything.

## Questions

Does someone have any idea on what's happening?

Is it a good idea to use the `AVPlayer` to stream 4K videos?

Which player does the Youtube iOS app use?

A lot of VR apps (Jaunt, Within, NYT VR, Sky VR, ...) are streaming 4K videos for virtual reality. Any idea on which player are they using?

#### Note

I am using Swift for this project but feel free to answer in Objective-C if you want!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the player resets properly? I mean if you are using any subviews in the player controller maybe some view is not deallocated properly. Try also to call on exiting player view controller:

```
player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(nil)
```

In case that you are dealing with **KVO** I can recommend you a library that helped me a lot. Check out the following: [PlayerView](https://github.com/davidlondono/PlayerView)

Comment: Hi! I'm almost sure that my player view controller is deallocated properly because the memory usage doesn't change over the whole experience...
Thanks for the wraper, I'll have a look.